# LokiJs - Error LoadDatabase in Ionic Framework App

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic-framework, lokijs

I need help, i have build an app with Ionic Framework (in Visual Studio 2015).
Now, i have a problem with LoadDatabase in Ripple.js (emulator android in NexusGalaxy).  
I'm inspired to guide: 
gonehybrid.com/how-to-use-lokijs-for-local-storage-in-your-ionic-app/

This is the error 
[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyAzx.png)

So, for first, i will inject the code here :)

Here, it is where the error occurred 
[it is where the error occurred](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEo5G.png)

I hope to get some help to solve this problem. 
I thank you in advance, 
Salvatore

Comment: You are trying to load database from a file or String data ? then use `loadJSON` and provide JSON String data to it.  Otherwise you need to define a `persistenceAdapter` in constructor.

Comment: Thx for the reply @S.D.
Mmmm, the original code (from blog) is: 
`var adapter = new LokiCordovaFSAdapter({"prefix": "loki"}); 
        _db = new Loki('birthdaysDB', 
                { 
                    autosave: true,
                    autosaveInterval: 1000, // 1 second
                    adapter: adapter
                });`

but I resolve my problem with: **persistenceAdapter: adapter**

Comment: but in lokijs, what is the difference between **adapter** and **persistenceAdapter**?